# Why is the square of curvature of a curve equal to the square of curvature of a normal plus the square of geodesic curvature?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I don't know what the normal curvature is. Is it the curvature of the normal direction of the surface? Or the curvature in the normal direction of the curve? Can we use graphics to explain the relationship between these three curvatures?

Comment: I don't know what book(s) you're reading, but you might try taking a look at my (free) differential geometry text, linked in my profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$(k_n, k_g)$](https://liavas.net/courses/math430/files/Surfaces_part3.pdf)

Yes normal curvature is in the osculating plane fully described by principal curvatures $k_1,k_2$  with Euler's relation.

Reference to figure at bottom of page 5.

There are *two distinct mutually perpendicular* components $(k_n, k_g)$ in normal and tangential planes respectively.

When surface normal and arc line normal of stand alone Frenet-Serret do not coincide we have a non-geodesic situation. The rate at which the angle deviates is  $ k_g.$

If it vanishes we are talking about a geodesic line.

In a globe the Equator is free of geodesic curvature. Other  parallels are latitudes which are not geodesics. At poles there is maximum  $k_g.$ The curvatures or accelerations in a dynamic situation e.g. banking of curves can be compared.

$ \tan \gamma= \dfrac{  k_g}{ k_n} $ describes the degree of slip-off and angle $\gamma$ lies in the plane spanned by the normal **N** and the binormal **B**.

[image: Non-geodesy]

In a *Loxodrome* (rhumb line) for example, the tangent starts as a geodesic at Equator and $k_g$ increases indefinitely while approaching towards either Pole along shrinking spiral paths.

Comment: Is the normal curvature the normal direction of a surface? Or the normal direction of the curve?

Comment: Normal direction to curve is not normal to surface if curve is not a geodesic in general. Normal direction to curve is normal to surface only when the curve on the surface is a geodesic.

Comment: In the linked notes they say that $\Gamma$ is a tensor. It is not, be careful.

Comment: @Narasimham Is gamma latitude?

Comment: @IvoTerek Is gamma latitude?

Comment: Did you read up about  Christoffel symbols and other isometric (first fundamental form dependent) quantities?

Comment: @Narasimham The small circle in the picture you give is parallel to the equator, so \gamma is the latitude of the small circle.

Comment: Yep. You can even extend this definition as a hypothesis for equal tendency to slip in non spherical convex/ surfaces of revolution.